# read data with decimal comma with readHTMLTable

Tags: xml, r

I have a dump from a database in the form of a HTML table.
My problem is that it uses comma as decimal character and I can't get readHTMLTable to handle it correctly. The values end up as factor instead of numeric. This could be solved externally, but I would like to do it all in R.

I tried to pass `dec=","` in the hope that the elipsis would pass it down the execution pipe but it didn't work.

Next trest was inspired from the help for readHTMLTable I tried using `elFun`

```
library(XML)
tryAsNumeric <- function(node) {
  val = xmlValue(node)
  ans = as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", val))
  if(is.numeric(ans))
    ans
  else
    val
}

tmp_list <- readHTMLTable("teeChart.xls", elFun = tryAsNumeric)
```

And ended up with this message

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()

Warning messages:

1: In (function (node)  ... : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In (function (node)  ... : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In (function (node)  ... : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In (function (node)  ... : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Truncated list for brevity.

Here is a reduced table for reproducibility. (teeChart.xls)

```
<table border="1">
<tr><td></td><td>Lägenhet 053</td><td></td><td>Lägenhet 054</td><td></td><td>Lägenhet 055</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Index</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>42309</td><td>20,8249988555908</td><td>42309</td><td>20,2000007629395</td><td>42309</td><td>22,2000007629395</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>42309,0416666667</td><td>20,7000007629395</td><td>42309,0416666667</td><td>20,2000007629395</td><td>42309,0416666667</td><td>22,125</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>42309,0833333333</td><td>20,6000003814697</td><td>42309,0833333333</td><td>20,2000007629395</td><td>42309,0833333333</td><td>22,0249996185303</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `colClasses`? Also from the help `?readHTMLTable`:

```
library(XML)
tryAsNumeric <- function(node) {
  val = xmlValue(node)
  ans = as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", val))
  if(all(is.numeric(ans)))
    ans
  else
    val
}
txt <- readLines(n=7)
<table border="1">
<tr><td></td><td>Lägenhet 053</td><td></td><td>Lägenhet 054</td><td></td><td>Lägenhet 055</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Index</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>42309</td><td>20,8249988555908</td><td>42309</td><td>20,2000007629395</td><td>42309</td><td>22,2000007629395</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>42309,0416666667</td><td>20,7000007629395</td><td>42309,0416666667</td><td>20,2000007629395</td><td>42309,0416666667</td><td>22,125</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>42309,0833333333</td><td>20,6000003814697</td><td>42309,0833333333</td><td>20,2000007629395</td><td>42309,0833333333</td><td>22,0249996185303</td></tr>
</table>
doc <- htmlParse(txt, asText=TRUE)
( res <- readHTMLTable(doc, elFun = tryAsNumeric, colClasses = rep("numeric", 7)) )
# $`NULL`
#   NA       NA     NA       NA   NA       NA     NA
# 1 NA       NA     NA       NA   NA       NA     NA
# 2  0 42309.00 20.825 42309.00 20.2 42309.00 22.200
# 3  1 42309.04 20.700 42309.04 20.2 42309.04 22.125
# 4  2 42309.08 20.600 42309.08 20.2 42309.08 22.025

str(res)
# List of 1
#  $ NULL:'data.frame': 4 obs. of  7 variables:
#   ..$ NA: num [1:4] NA 0 1 2
#   ..$ NA: num [1:4] NA 42309 42309 42309
#   ..$ NA: num [1:4] NA 20.8 20.7 20.6
#   ..$ NA: num [1:4] NA 42309 42309 42309
#   ..$ NA: num [1:4] NA 20.2 20.2 20.2
#   ..$ NA: num [1:4] NA 42309 42309 42309
#   ..$ NA: num [1:4] NA 22.2 22.1 22
```

---

```
library(XML)
txt <- readLines(n=7)
<table border="1">
<tr><td></td><td>Lägenhet 053</td><td></td><td>Lägenhet 054</td><td></td><td>Lägenhet 055</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Index</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>42309</td><td>20,8249988555908</td><td>42309</td><td>20,2000007629395</td><td>42309</td><td>22,2000007629395</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>42309,0416666667</td><td>20,7000007629395</td><td>42309,0416666667</td><td>20,2000007629395</td><td>42309,0416666667</td><td>22,125</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>42309,0833333333</td><td>20,6000003814697</td><td>42309,0833333333</td><td>20,2000007629395</td><td>42309,0833333333</td><td>22,0249996185303</td></tr>
</table>
doc <- htmlParse(txt)
m <- as.matrix(readHTMLTable(doc, which=1))
colnames(m) <- m[1,]
m <- m[-1, ]
m <- gsub(",", ".", m)
as.data.frame(structure(as.numeric(m), .Dim=dim(m), .Dimnames = dimnames(m)))
#   Index        X      Y        X    Y        X      Y
# 1     0 42309.00 20.825 42309.00 20.2 42309.00 22.200
# 2     1 42309.04 20.700 42309.04 20.2 42309.04 22.125
# 3     2 42309.08 20.600 42309.08 20.2 42309.08 22.025
```

Comment: colClasses seems to solve the problem with numeric vs factor. Still I gets all these warnings about NA introduction on coercion. Also I don't know the number of variables for the rep on the full database.

Comment: Imho forget about `readHTMLTable` and do it "old school" - see my edit.